# How to run already deployed to azure app service container?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I use azure pipeline to build and deploy my docker container (ASP.Net core 3.1).
All steps finish successfully, I can see my container on Azure registry and App service portal pages. But seems like the instance is not running on App Service because I can see only "Starting page" which suggests me to deploy code and my swagger page returns 404.

So the question is: **How to run already deployed by pipeline image?**

My azure pipeline yml file:

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

  trigger:
  - master
  
  resources:
  - repo: self
  
  variables:
    tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build image
    jobs:  
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        # run tests
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Run tests
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: 'ProjectName'
          dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName/API/Dockerfile'
          buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName/'
          containerRegistry: AzureContainerRegistryConnection
          tags: |
            $(tag)
  
    # Deploy stage to your App Service
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to App Service
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
        displayName: Deploy to App Service
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'my_free_subscription(my-subscription-id)'
          appName: 'app-service'
          containers: 'projectnamecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/RepositoryName:$(tag)'
```

**UPD**

I dunno mb it's a trouble with app service settings in terraform

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "app_service_plab" {
  name                = "app-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.store_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.store_group.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  sku {
    tier = "FREE"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "app_service" {
  name                = "app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.store_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.store_group.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app_service_plab.id
}
```

**UPD2**

Started to use new deployment task AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 and it does do something I can even see logs on app service machine now.

```
- stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to App Service
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
        inputs:
          ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
          azureSubscription: 'free_subscription(id)'
          appType: 'webAppContainer'
          WebAppName: 'app-service'
          DockerNamespace: 'containerregistry.azurecr.io'
          DockerRepository: 'myRepository'
          DockerImageTag: $(tag)
          StartupCommand: 'az acr login --password $(REGISTRY_PASSWORD_UNSECRET) --username $(REGISTRY_USERNAME_UNSECRET) --name (MyRegistry)containerregistry.azurecr.io && docker run'
          appSettings: |
            -CONNECTION_STRING $(CONNECTION_STRING_UNSECRET)
```

But seems like az acr login doesn't work :(

Now I'm getting such error

2020-09-19T19:29:08.498Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-09-19T19:34:00.826Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: MyContainercontainerregistry.azurecr.io/MyRepo:85
2020-09-19T19:34:01.151Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://MyContainercontainerregistry.azurecr.io/v2/MyRepo/manifests/85: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

Answer (score 0):

Use docker run cmd.

Add the task Docker->delete the field cmd content and add the cmd `run`
[image]

Comment: Do you think it's possible to run docker image on app service machine by pipeline docker task? I think that task will run docker image on agent machine instead.

Comment: Hi @Vlad, run docker image on app service, we can open azure portal, create app service and select container to create app service, It will run the image automatically.

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, currently I have "login failed" error when try pull docker image from azure registry on app service machine after pipeline deploy step execution. Now I am investigating possible fixes.
I tried to do like you suggested by terraform provider but it has some bugs with altering the existent instances of app service :(

Comment: Hi @Vlad, could you please share the detail log here? I will check it and help you. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, added UPD2 section with new configuration and error message.

Comment: Hi @Vlad, Thanks for your sharing, I am testing it, please wait.